# Firebase Data Posting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to post data on a particular structure in firebase database but not able to get the expected result. Need the structure like:

```
ABC->DEVICE_ID-COORDINATES->DATE->PUSHKEY (EX:-KSHJDWFQ)->NOW CHILD LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE.
```

I am not able to push the child to date as the expected pattern.

**Expected pattern:**

```
        {
          "ABC" : {               
            "1_861645036247906" : {  ///device id
              "co-ordinates" : {     ///coordinates
                "15-11-2017" : {     ///date
                  "KSHJDWFQ" : {     ///push key
                    "latitude" : 4564564,
                    "longitude" : 45454545
                  },
                  "khgjhkhjk" : {
                    "latitude" : 456456456,
                    "longitude" : 435345345
                  }
                },
                "16-11-2017" : {
                  "KSHJDWFQ" : {
                    "latitude" : 4564564,
                    "longitude" : 45454545
                  },
                  "khgjhkhjk" : {
                    "latitude" : 456456456,
                    "longitude" : 435345345
                  }
                }
              },
              "driver_details" : {
                "driver_id" : 1,
                "driver_name" : "avik"
              }
            }
          },
        }
```

**My result is coming like this:**

```
        {
          "ABC" : {
            "2_861645036247906" : {
              "-Kz8lFh9B86pCj62gcN3" : {
                "coordinates" : {
                  "17-11-2017" : {
                    "latitude" : "22.5735875",
                    "longitude" : "88.431699"
                  }
                }
              },
              "-Kz8ldboHvGS5QabIVZY" : {
                "coordinates" : {
                  "17-11-2017" : {
                    "latitude" : "22.5735875",
                    "longitude" : "88.431699"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

**This is the code I have done:**

```
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    String child_node = KPUtils.get_driver_IdPreference(mContext) + "_" + KPUtils.getdeviceid(mContext);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://pool------").child(child_node);

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    Map<String, String> m_coordinates = new HashMap<>();
    m_coordinates.put("latitude", st_latitude);
    m_coordinates.put("longitude", st_longitude);
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> gens = new HashMap<>();
    gens.put(date, m_coordinates);

    Map<String, String> m_driverdetails = new HashMap<>();
    m_driverdetails.put("driver_id", "1");
    m_driverdetails.put("driver_name", "Avik");

    driver.setCoordinates(gens);
    //driver.setDriver_details(m_driverdetails);
    ref.push().setValue(driver);
```

Comment: what's in ABC class ?

Comment: I have edited the question.Driver is the setter getter class

Comment: https://pool.firebaseio.com/ABC   (is the firebase url where i am posting the data)

Comment: you haven't added your date hashmap to your driver class

Comment: No i haven't added the date in the driver class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this...

```
ref.child("abc")
    .child("device id")
    .child("coordinates")
    .child(date)
    .push()
    .setValue(m_coordinates);
```